# Is there a way to safely collect the data from a returned char*?

Tags: c

I am working on a project for fun to learn C programming, and in Java, I know that I can just obtain a String from a method through a simple return statement. However, in C, I believe it is returning the address of the pointer or garbage data. Here is some basic code:

```
// In Main Method
char *words = getWords();
// ...
// In getWords
char *getWords() {
char *input; //Well-formatted input.
// Filler code that collects data through file or text entry with 256 max char.
char str[256];
scan("%s", str);
input = str;
return input;
}
```

Comment: Also, I tested the input by printing it within the getWords method, and it is just fine.

Comment: What does `input` point to when it's returned?

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the pointer as an argument and store the data there itself. Declaring local pointer and returning it is not a good way of doing it. It may lead to dangling pointer.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dangling-void-null-wild-pointers/

Comment: According to your link it *does* lead to a dangling pointer. No 'may' about it.

Answer (score -1):

After further review, I have discovered that this is the problem:

```
char str[256];
```

Should be static:

```
static char str[256];
```

Now it returns the correct inputted string.